# GCP workflow: load external sql file?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-workflows

I am planning to have a Cloud Scheduler that calls a GCP Workflows every day at 8 a.m. My GCP Workflows will have around 15 different `steps` and will be only transformations (update, delete, add) on BigQuery. Some queries will be quite long and I am wondering if there is a way to load a `.sql` file into a GCP Workflows `task1.yaml`?

```
#workflow entrypoint
ProcessItem:
  params: [project, gcsPath]
  steps:
    - initialize:
        assign:
          - dataset: wf_samples
          - input: ${gcsPath}
          - sqlQuery: QUERY HERE
   ...
```

Comment: Likely one can load it from bucket: https://gist.github.com/pentium10/e3dba47b13a3ef34e4556e543020139f#file-workflow_gcsobjectslist-yaml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do something similar: (of course you can assign this to a variable like `input`)

```
#workflow entrypoint
main:
  steps:
    - getSqlfile:
        call: http.get
        args:
          url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jisaw/sqlzoo-solutions/master/select-in-select.sql
          headers:
            Content-Type: "text/plain"
        result: queryFromFile
    - final:
        return: ${queryFromFile.body}
```

For Cloud Storage that may look like:

```
 call: http.get
    args:
      url: https://storage.cloud.google.com/................./q1.sql
      headers:
        Content-Type: "text/plain"
      auth:
        type: OIDC
    result: queryFromFile
```

Or event with this format (different URL syntax + OAuth2)

```
call: http.get
    args:
      url: https://storage.googleapis.com/................./q1.sql
      headers:
        Content-Type: "text/plain"
      auth:
        type: OAuth2
    result: queryFromFile
```

Make sure that invoker has the right permission to access the Cloud Storage file.

> Note: On further testing, this to work correctly the `text/plain`
> mime-type must be set on the GCS file.

Comment: Won't you be limited by the max variable size if you download to Workflow the file content?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I understood that limit is being lifted as we speak.

Comment: Thanks for this share, but the url from gcs is redirected and so, it leads to an error at the end of the workflow. Either we do redirection from the call or we use Cloud Functions, in my opinion...

Comment: @Sebastien something is off on permissions if redirects. I have the 2nd example in production and it pulls the SQL from it. We are using to read the long SQL from GCS file. Please note that the 2nd URL has the *googleapis* format. Pay attention to the link format. I just rerun our example and it works without a redirect. Also check the proper mimetype of the file. Mine is `.SQL` extension `text/plain` on GCS.

Comment: that's a great answer but for me it works fine if and only if I set a files' content-type on GCS (e.g. plain/text). But by default  when I upload an sql file, its application/x-sql and the API return bytes regardless of content-type='text/plain' header. Any idea on how to download a file's content regardless its content-type on GCS?